# Hibernate Criteria: Projecting Count with group by clause

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate, criteria, nhibernate-criteria

I want to execute the following SQL

```
select count(*) as myCount from user group by name;
```

I came up with the following criteria for the same

```
DetachedCriteria.ForClass(typeof(UserDTO))
    .setProjections(Projections.ProjectionList()
                        .Add(Projections.rowCount(),"myCount")
                        .Add(Projections.groupProperty("this.name"));
```

I get the result back as pair of the count and name,How can I get just the count from this.

Comment: What's the use of getting several numbers without any reference of what they correspond to?

Comment: the application which I am working on has an architecture which uses repositories for data access. There are predefined repositories to fetch objects.the objects thus fetched need to implement certain interfaces. Under such architecture I cannot retrieve an object the one returned by this criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with Criteria, but it's easy with HQL. It's exactly the same string as your SQL query, but with entity/property names instead of table/column ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can use count distinct if there is only one group by column.

HQL:

```
select count(distinct name) as myCount from user
```

Criteria:

```
DetachedCriteria.ForClass(typeof(UserDTO))
.setProjections(Projections.ProjectionList()
                    .Add(Projections.countDistinct("name"),"myCount"));
```